# Android Intents: Start activity using class name from another app that has the same sharedUserId

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, shared

All my apps have the same sharedUserId. I would like to start a class of another app using the class of my current app. I want to use intent extras but I do not want to use intent URLs. I also would prefer not to have to change the AndroidManifest of my target activity's app.

Comment: `All my apps have the same sharedUserId` I would highly suggest not doing that.

Comment: It is necessary from a user perspective that logging in to one app logs in to the others as well. I can either lock the login cookie to my sharedUserId or I can make it publicly available to all apps. Also it is not possible to down the road add a sharedUserId to an app that does not have one without requiring an uninstall and loss of data (unless they fix this in future releases). @Falmarri, All that aside, I would still like to know why it is preferred not to use sharedUserId.

Comment: `All my apps have the same sharedUserId` : Please don't do this unless there is a strong reason. Having sharedUid means a vulnerability in one app can be used to exploit you other apps too on the same device.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its pretty easy since you have the sharedUserId set.

```
Intent res = new Intent();
String mPackage = "com.your.package";
String mClass = ".actYouAreLaunching";
res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
startActivity(res);
```

And that's all there is to it. You can add intent extras like you normally would.

Comment: you can omit `new ComponentName(...)` by using `Intent.setClassName(String pack, String className)`